# Mocking pathlib.Path I/O methods in a maintainable way which tests functionality not implementation

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocks

I have a function that constructs a path based on a function of inputs and creates the parent directory.

When writing a unit test for this function, I want to mock the I/O part of the function, namely the `.exists()` and `.mkdir()` methods of the `pathlib.Path` objects.  However, since both are not called until the path has been constructed, I find myself reconstructing the implementation using a long chain of `return_value.__truediv__` accesses, such as below:

```py
import pathlib
import unittest.mock
import datetime


def get(base, timestamp, channel):
    base = pathlib.Path(base)
    path = base / "tofu" / timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d") / f"{channel:>02d}" / "quinoa.txt"
    if path.exists():
        print(path, "exists")
    else:
        path.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
    return path


@unittest.mock.patch("pathlib.Path", autospec=True)
def test_get(pP):
    pP.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.\
                    __truediv__.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.\
                    exists.return_value = False
    get("quorn", datetime.datetime.now(), 42)
    pP.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.\
                    __truediv__.return_value.__truediv__.return_value.\
                    parent.mkdir.assert_called_once()
```

This test passes, but I have several concerns:

- It is testing implementation rather than functionality.  If I were to rewrite the second line in `get` to read `path = base / timestamp.strftime("tofu%Y%m%d") / f{channel:>02d}` / `"quinoa.txt"`, the functionality would be identical, but the test would fail as I wouldn't be mocking the right value anymore.
- It is hard to read and easy to miscount the depth of `__truediv__.return_value` chain.

Apart from moving the I/O out of `get`, can I mock this in another way, that does not share those limitations?  Or does the difficulty of writing a good test (with mock) telling me my function is too complex, despite it's small size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm no professional when it comes to testing. But it looks like your code is a perfect example on non-test friendly code. And is why SRP, [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is such a big thing.

From my perspective, your function is doing two things:

1. Making `path`.
2. Ensuring `path` exists.

If you change your code so that those are two distinct functions than you can test more easily. And finally have `get` as a helper function.

```py
def generate_path(base, timestamp, channel):
    return (
        pathlib.Path(base)
        / "tofu"
        / timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        / f"{channel:>02d}"
        / "quinoa.txt"
    )


def ensure_exists(path):
    if path.exists():
        print(path, "exists")
    else:
        path.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)


def get(base, timestamp, channel):
    path = generate_path()
    ensure_exists(path)
    return path
```

I believe someone more versed in testing would be able to say something more enlightening about what you should unittest and what you should mock. But from my POV I don't see why the implementation details of `generate_path` should matter, all that matters is you get the correct result. The implementation details of `ensure_exists`, however, do matter, as it can be hard to test file interactions. But with [etene's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237063) changes this statement can suddenly become false.

Overall I agree with etene's answer, but I think my answer should help when designing your code for testing.

```py
import pathlib
import unittest.mock
import datetime


def generate_path(base, timestamp, channel):
    return (
        pathlib.Path(base)
        / timestamp.strftime("tofu/%Y%m%d")
        / f"{channel:>02d}"
        / "quinoa.txt"
    )


def ensure_exists(path):
    if path.exists():
        print(path, "exists")
    else:
        path.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
    return path


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    BASE = "quorn"
    TIME = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    CHANNEL = 42
    PATH = pathlib.Path("quorn/tofu/20200211/42/quinoa.txt")

    def test_generate_path(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            generate_path(self.BASE, self.TIME, self.CHANNEL),
            self.PATH,
        )

    @unittest.mock.patch("pathlib.Path", autospec=True)
    def test_ensure_exists(self, pP):
        pP.exists.return_value = False
        ensure_exists(pP)
        pP.parent.mkdir.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with your suggestion of refactoring the code to make it more testable. "Do one thing and do it well", as goes the saying. I just didn't think of this angle when writing my answer.

Comment: Don't sweat it @etene I didn't think of your solution either ;P Things like this are what make the site great IMO

Answer (score 9):

Mocking system calls, especially those with side effects (`mkdir()`), is difficult and error prone.

I would rather use a temporary directory for test purposes. This approach has the added advantage of *really* testing your FS manipluation code.

```py
import datetime
import os
import pathlib

from contextlib import contextmanager
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory


@contextmanager
def temporary_test_dir():
    oldpwd = os.getcwd()
    with TemporaryDirectory("test-path") as td:
        try:
            os.chdir(td)
            yield
        finally:
            os.chdir(oldpwd)


def get(base, timestamp, channel):
    base = pathlib.Path(base)
    path = base / "tofu" / timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d") / f"{channel:>02d}" / "quinoa.txt"
    if path.exists():
        print(path, "exists")
    else:
        path.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
    return path


@temporary_test_dir()
def test_get():
    # All relative FS operations will be made in a temporary directory
    result = get("quorn", datetime.datetime.now(), 42)
    assert result.parent.exists()
```

I'm not sure what is the point of the tested function, but it doesn't matter for this example's sake.

If you *really* need to mock the filesystem part, I would suggest using an existing library such as [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/), although I have never had such a need.

Comment: Thank you for posting this as an answer. With added details to boot! :)